# Dúvida com SELECT em banco MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Eu preciso de um sql que, na tabela abaixo, traga sempre a última inserção para cada usuário. Tentei com distinct porém não funcionou. Então, no caso abaixo o sql iria trazer os resultados da linha 2 e 5. Detalhe que existem mais colunas (cidade, pais, endereço, etc...) e que precisam aparecer no resultado final.

```
DATA----------------------ID---NOME

2017-07-17 16:37:38  || 1   || Lucas    
2017-07-17 16:38:03  || 1   || Lucas    
2017-07-17 16:38:37  || 2   || Juliana  
2017-07-17 16:38:47  || 2   || Juliana  
2017-07-17 16:39:00  || 2   || Juliana
```

Depois de tanto pesquisar não achei nada. Essa tabela terá mais inserções com usuários diferentes (sempre 1 id pra cada usuário) mas só exemplifiquei para entenderem.

Comment: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/512214-selecionando-item-max/?do=findComment&comment=2030107 veja se ajuda

Comment: Bem-vindo Lucas, para um melhor proveito desse site comece lendo esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas e depois desse também  https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas

Comment: Desculpe qualquer erro, foi minha primeira pergunta aqui !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A query abaixo resolve seu problema**   só substituir `tabela` pelo nome da sua tabela

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tabela t1
WHERE t1.data = (SELECT MAX(t2.data)
FROM tabela t2
WHERE t2.nome = t1.nome)
```

Tabela usada para teste

[image: Tabela de teste]

Resultado da consulta

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Realmente isso solucionou o meu problema, seguia na mesma ideia do link do Motta, Muito obrigado !!

Answer (score 1):

Não consigo abrir do trabalho o link apresentado pelo Motta, mas deve estar citando a função `MAX()`. Só completando a query, ficaria assim:

```
SELECT max(data), id, nome, cidade, pais, endereco
FROM tabela
GROUP BY id, nome, cidade, pais, endereco
ORDER BY id
```

Para os outros campos da tabela, é necessário adicionar cada um deles tanto no `SELECT` quanto na parte `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Seu SELECT funciona, porém só retorna id e nome e existem varias outras colunas "cidade, pais, endereço, etc..." como ficaria sem ter que listar todas elas no select, ou seja sem ter que fazer SELECT max(data), id, nome, cidade, pais, endereço, ..... A minha pergunta é no sentido de tornar sua resposta mais adequada a pergunta do autor.

Comment: Adicionei outras colunas que ele menciona no exemplo, mas sem precisar especificar as colunas extras, é do jeito que você montou.